# How to install and configure SAS storage driver

Tags: drivers

We've recently installed a LSI SAS2008 (also known as a LSI SAS 9211 8i) HBA on our machine here. The purpose of this is to connect to a storewize v3700. The storewize is mapped to to the machine, and upon boot we can see the mapped volumes appear in the BIOS. However ubuntu is able to see/map/mount them. We tried installing the mpt2sas driver, however in lshw storage is still coming up as unclaimed, and apparently used by none in lsmod. See below for output of lsmod and lshw. The driver we installed came from here http://www.lsi.com/products/host-bus-adapters/pages/lsi-sas-9211-8i.aspx

Any advice/tips would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
Module                Size    Used By 
mpt2sas               155628  0 
raid_class             13554  1 mpt2sas
megaraid_sas          100086  2 
scsi_transport_sas     41034  1 mpt2sas
ahci                   34062  0 
bnx2                   85175  0 
libahci                32424  1 ahci



*-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: RD890S PCI Express bridge for GPP2 port 1
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:0c.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm pciexpress msi ht normal_decode bus_master     cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:54 ioport:d000(size=4096) memory:80000000-805fffff 
           *-storage UNCLAIMED
                description: Serial Attached SCSI controller
                product: SAS2008 PCI-Express Fusion-MPT SAS-2 [Falcon]
                vendor: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
                version: 03
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: storage pm pciexpress vpd msi msix cap_list
                configuration: latency=0
                resources: ioport:d000(size=256) memory:804c0000-804c3fff memory:80080000-800bffff memory:80000000-8007ffff memory:804c4000-80503fff memory:800c0000-804bffff
```

Answer (score 0):

sorted it with this link :: https://baldpenguin.blogspot.co.uk/2014/04/

has to delete the raid.

Show raid dar index with this command :: sas2ircu LIST

```
root@lancache:~# sas2ircu LIST
LSI Corporation SAS2 IR Configuration Utility.
Version 13.00.00.00 (2012.02.17)
Copyright (c) 2009-2012 LSI Corporation. All rights reserved.


         Adapter      Vendor  Device                       SubSys  SubSys
 Index    Type          ID      ID    Pci Address          Ven ID  Dev ID
 -----  ------------  ------  ------  -----------------    ------  ------
   0     SAS2008     1000h    72h   00h:01h:00h:00h      1028h   1f1dh
SAS2IRCU: Utility Completed Successfully.
```

Index is 0

Now I need the Raid Volume ID

```
root@lancache:~# sas2ircu 0  DISPLAY
LSI Corporation SAS2 IR Configuration Utility.
Version 13.00.00.00 (2012.02.17)
Copyright (c) 2009-2012 LSI Corporation. All rights reserved.

Read configuration has been initiated for controller 0
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Controller information
------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Controller type                         : SAS2008
  BIOS version                            : 7.11.01.00
  Firmware version                        : 7.15.04.00
  Channel description                     : 1 Serial Attached SCSI
  Initiator ID                            : 0
  Maximum physical devices                : 39
  Concurrent commands supported           : 2607
  Slot                                    : 1
  Segment                                 : 0
  Bus                                     : 1
  Device                                  : 0
  Function                                : 0
  RAID Support                            : Yes
------------------------------------------------------------------------
IR Volume information
------------------------------------------------------------------------
IR volume 1
  Volume ID                               : 79
  Status of volume                        : Inactive, Okay (OKY)
  Volume wwid                             : 0edea3a351dff36d
  RAID level                              : RAID0
  Size (in MB)                            : 7629392
  Physical hard disks                     :
  PHY[0] Enclosure#/Slot#                 : 1:1
  PHY[1] Enclosure#/Slot#                 : 1:0
  PHY[2] Enclosure#/Slot#                 : 0:0
  PHY[3] Enclosure#/Slot#                 : 0:0
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Physical device information
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Initiator at ID #0

Device is a Hard disk
  Enclosure #                             : 0
  Slot #                                  : 0
  SAS Address                             : 0000000-0-0000-0000
  State                                   : Missing (MIS)
  Manufacturer                            : SEAGATE
  Model Number                            :
  Firmware Revision                       :
  Serial No                               : Z1P14BEL0000C225
  GUID                                    : N/A
  Drive Type                              : Undetermined

Device is a Hard disk
  Enclosure #                             : 0
  Slot #                                  : 0
  SAS Address                             : 0000000-0-0000-0000
  State                                   : Missing (MIS)
  Manufacturer                            : SEAGATE
  Model Number                            :
  Firmware Revision                       :
  Serial No                               : Z1P00HSD0000S129
  GUID                                    : N/A
  Drive Type                              : Undetermined

Device is a Hard disk
  Enclosure #                             : 1
  Slot #                                  : 0
  SAS Address                             : 5000c50-0-342c-217d
  State                                   : Optimal (OPT)
  Size (in MB)/(in sectors)               : 1907729/3907029167
  Manufacturer                            : SEAGATE
  Model Number                            : ST2000NM0001
  Firmware Revision                       : 0001
  Serial No                               : Z1P0288F0000S137KRQ9
  GUID                                    : 5000c500342c217f
  Protocol                                : SAS
  Drive Type                              : SAS_HDD

Device is a Hard disk
  Enclosure #                             : 1
  Slot #                                  : 1
  SAS Address                             : 5000c50-0-8d46-33cd
  State                                   : Optimal (OPT)
  Size (in MB)/(in sectors)               : 1907729/3907029167
  Manufacturer                            : SEAGATE
  Model Number                            : ST2000NM0001
  Firmware Revision                       : 0002
  Serial No                               : Z1P2JXMV0000C2426MCF
  GUID                                    : 5000c5008d4633cf
  Protocol                                : SAS
  Drive Type                              : SAS_HDD
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Enclosure information
------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Enclosure#                              : 1
  Logical ID                              : 5782bcb0:2a464900
  Numslots                                : 8
  StartSlot                               : 0
------------------------------------------------------------------------
SAS2IRCU: Command DISPLAY Completed Successfully.
SAS2IRCU: Utility Completed Successfully.

So the Volum ID os  79 ...

Now to delete the volume.

root@lancache:~# sas2ircu 0 DELETEVOLUME 79
LSI Corporation SAS2 IR Configuration Utility.
Version 13.00.00.00 (2012.02.17)
Copyright (c) 2009-2012 LSI Corporation. All rights reserved.

You are about to delete an existing RAID Volume on a controller. This command
will delete the specified RAID volume and associated HotSpare drive(s).

WARNING: Proceeding with this operation may cause data loss or data
         corruption. Are you sure you want to proceed (YES/NO)? yes

WARNING: This is you last chance to abort this operation. Do you wish
         to abort (YES/NO)? no
Please wait, may take up to a minute...
SAS2IRCU: Volume deleted successfully.
SAS2IRCU: Command DELETEVOLUME Completed Successfully.
SAS2IRCU: Utility Completed Successfully.
```

Now the disks are back to normal

```
root@lancache:~# lshw -c disk
  *-disk:0
       description: SCSI Disk
       product: ST2000NM0001
       vendor: SEAGATE
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sdc
       version: 0001
       serial: Z1P0288F0000S137KRQ9
       size: 1863GiB (2TB)
       capabilities: 7200rpm
       configuration: ansiversion=6 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
  *-disk:1
       description: SCSI Disk
       product: ST2000NM0001
       vendor: SEAGATE
       physical id: 0.1.0
       bus info: scsi@0:0.1.0
       logical name: /dev/sdb
       version: 0002
       serial: Z1P2JXMV0000C2426MCF
       size: 1863GiB (2TB)
       capabilities: 7200rpm
       configuration: ansiversion=6 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
```

Now I can fdisk the drives and set them up with zfs.

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sdc: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

I know it's an old post but worth an update for everyone.